# Unable to bottom align a image within a div, which is inside another div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Still looking for solution:

**updated jsfiddle 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/sharath83/hyaswq1f/6/

```
**css**
body { margin: 0; font-size: 1em; line-height: 1.4; }
.fluid {
clear: both;
margin-left: 0;
width: 100%;
float: left;
display: block;
}
.gridContainer {
width: 68.6%;
max-width:960px;
/*max-width: 1232px;*/
padding-left: 0.75%;
padding-right: 0.75%;
margin: auto;
clear: none;
float: none;
margin-left: auto;
}

.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { *zoom: 1; }

.responsive-scale-homepage1{
width:100%;
padding-bottom: 66.666666666667%; /* 960px/1440px */
background-image:url(images/homepage-main-1.jpg);
background-size:100%;
background-position:center; /* IE fix */
display:block;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-color:#B99394;
}

.clear {
clear:both;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;    
}
.arrow_wrapper{
vertical-align:bottom;
display:table-cell;
}
.db_arrow{
content:url(images/dark-blue-arrow.png);
background-color:#AD3E40;
}
```

**html**

```
        <div class="fluid body responsive-scale-homepage1">
            <div class="arrow_wrapper">
                        <a href="#transparency"><div class="db_arrow"></div></a>
            </div>        
        </div>

    </div>
```

In the above jsfiddle i tried making what i am looking for. There is an arrow (facing downwards, which when clicked will scroll down to next image), aligned it to bottom of a background image and middle to it.

But am not able to align it bottom and center/middle. It doesn't fit in for any of the screens too, mobile/tab/desktop. This is for a responsive web!

Can anyone help me on this one please, thank you.

Comment: Your images don't work in jsfiddle. Also, instead of using an empty div inside an anchor for your arrow, why not just use the anchor as your arrow?

Comment: @slime.Unable to upload image on jsfiddle. Am sorry, i didn't get you.

Comment: How do you plan on doing a responsive arrow? If not needed, then this is easy by way of absolute positioning.

Comment: Well the arrow image size will be changed for mobile/tab/desktop screens, i change the width.

Comment: could you please advise as to what the 'small red square' is repsenting?

Comment: as am unable to upload any image, it displays as some box.

Here is what am looking for, there is a background image, and there is an arrow above it, the arrow should align to bottom of the background image, the  arrow is pointing down, to be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-position:center bottom;`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/hyaswq1f/2/)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.4;
}
.fluid {
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
.responsive-scale-homepage1 {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 66.666666666667%;
  /* 960px/1440px */
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/300);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center bottom;
  /* IE fix */
  background-size: auto;
  display: block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #A6A6A6;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.arrow_wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 40%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
}
.db_arrow {
  content: url(images/dark-blue-arrow.png);
  position: absolute;
  width: 2.5%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin: auto auto;
  background-color: #AD3E40;
}
```

```html
<div class="fluid body responsive-scale-homepage1">

  <div class="clear arrow_wrapper">
    <a href="#transparency">
      <div class="db_arrow"></div>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

As for aligning your arrow, [is this what you were looking for?](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/hyaswq1f/3/)

Comment: Well the arrow should bottom align within the grey box.

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sharath83/hyaswq1f/5/

Comment: tried 'background-position:center bottom;', but the arrow doesn't align

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the dimension of your arrow image but here's a solution for you.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g1ar4pmq/)

Added `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` to your `.arrow-wrapper` to get the arrow to the bottom and then on your `db_arrow` class I specified a width and used `margin: auto;` to center the image.

```js
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
.fluid {
    clear: both;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.gridContainer {
    width: 68.6%;
    max-width:960px;
    /*max-width: 1232px;*/
    padding-left: 0.75%;
    padding-right: 0.75%;
    margin: auto;
    clear: none;
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content:"";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}
.responsive-scale-homepage1 {
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom: 66.666666666667%;
    /* 960px/1440px */
    background-image:url(images/homepage-main-1.jpg);
    background-size:100%;
    background-position:center;
    /* IE fix */
    display:block;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:#B99394;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.arrow_wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
.db_arrow {
    content:url(images/dark-blue-arrow.png);
    width: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color:#AD3E40;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
    <div class="fluid body responsive-scale-homepage1">
        <div class="arrow_wrapper"> <a href="#transparency"><div class="db_arrow"></div></a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Press.the problem here is the arrow changes it's position when the screen is viewed on mobile and tab. So it doesn't work.

Comment: @Press.Missed something in CSS, am checking again.